# Django: Accounts activated automatically when sending verification emails

Tags: django, html-email

I have a problem in activating accounts on Django.
When I send a clickable verification link by email, the account is getting activated automatically without needing the users to click on the link (I saw that the account was indeed activated without needing to click on it).

On the other hand, when I send a non clickable link (so by removing the http:// in the beginning), the client can copy the link and paste and verify his account normally.

I need to send a clickable link that require a user to manually click on it so his account gets activated.

In **views.py**

**Registation function**

```
mail_subject = 'Activate your blog account.'
        message = render_to_string('main/acc_active_email.html', {
            'user': user,
            'domain': example.com,
            'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
            'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
        })
        to_email = form2.cleaned_data.get('email')
        email = EmailMessage(
            mail_subject, message, to=[to_email, ]
        )
        email.send()
```

**Activation function**

```
def activate(request, uidb64, token):
try:
    uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
    user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
    user = None
if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
    user.is_active = True
    user.save()
    login(request, user)
    data = 1
    context = {'data': data}

    return render(request=request, template_name="main/accept_email.html", context=context)
else:
    return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')
```

In confirmation email:

```
    {% autoescape off %}
Hi {{ user.username }},

Please click on the link to confirm your registration,
http://{{ domain }}{% url 'main:activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}

{% endautoescape %}
```

I tried playing with the SITE_ID in settings.py switching between example.com and http://example.com but did not work.

Can you please help ?

**------------------EDIT-----------------**

I found out that users can manually do an activation when clicking on the "clickable" link on EMAIL/GMAIL application on Android.

Apparently the automatic activation happens when the user opens the activation email on the browser (for instance https://outlook.office365.com/mail/) and before manually clicking on the link.

What went wrong ?

Kind regards,

Marvin

Comment: well you probably didn't set the default user's `is_active` to false. Can  you post your models.py where you extend the user model (if you did)

Comment: @quqa123 thanks for your reply. I made sure that by default is_active is false. It is just when the user opens the email in the browser (outlook office 365 for instance) that it looks like the clickable link is automatically clicked. Before opening the mail is_active is false, after opening the mail it becomes true (checking through admin session), as if the browser runs the link automatically. (this is not happening on mobile email app)

Answer (score 0):

For others using this code, I had the same problem.
The issue is some email clients processing the email as HTML and generating a preview link - which automatically activates the account and so the link is voided before you click on it.
Though on the plus side the account is activated.

Change the sent email to a text file to fix.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33428204)

Comment: Umm.... it exactly answers the question?

Change main/accept_email.html to main/accept_email.txt

exactly as I said above, and it will work. 
What part can you not understand?